# sum 2 fields by row and query max value by day per month

Tags: sql

I have used SQL for simple queries, but now need to perform something a bit more complex. I am not sure how to nest the queries.

I have one table with the following columns:

```
Date, Daily Power, Daily Power 1, Daily power2
```

I need to find that `max daily values` and then filter by months. Also I need `Daily Power 1` and `Daily Power 2` summed into a new column.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What rdbms are you using? I'm also missing sample data, a desired result and what you've tried.

Comment: Edit your question to gave us bit more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the problem with your table is that the data is not normalized since you have 3 columns each containing a separate value for `DailyPower`.

One way that you can easily get the result that you need is to *unpivot* the data using a `UNION ALL` query.

This query will take the data from the multiple columns and turn it into multiple rows for use:

```
select date, 'DailyPower' as col, DailyPower as value
from yourtable
union all
select date, 'DailyPower1' as col, DailyPower1 as value
from yourtable
union all
select date, 'DailyPower2' as col, DailyPower2 as value
from yourtable
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/982c5/1). This query takes the data and converts it into the result:

```
|       DATE |         COL | VALUE |
------------------------------------
| 2012-01-01 |  DailyPower |   456 |
| 2012-01-02 |  DailyPower |   789 |
| 2012-02-01 |  DailyPower |    23 |
| 2012-01-01 | DailyPower1 |   789 |
| 2012-01-02 | DailyPower1 |   235 |
| 2012-02-01 | DailyPower1 |    89 |
| 2012-01-01 | DailyPower2 |    65 |
| 2012-01-02 | DailyPower2 |    45 |
| 2012-02-01 | DailyPower2 |    10 |
```

Once the data is in the rows, then it is easier to get the `max()` value by date.

Your query would be similar to the following:

```
select date, 
  max(value) MaxDailyPower,
  sum(case when col in ('DailyPower1', 'DailyPower2') then value end) TotalDailyPower
from
(
  select date, 'DailyPower' as col, DailyPower as value
  from yourtable
  union all
  select date, 'DailyPower1' as col, DailyPower1 as value
  from yourtable
  union all
  select date, 'DailyPower2' as col, DailyPower2 as value
  from yourtable
) src
where date >= '2012-01-01' 
  and date <= '2012-12-31'
group by date
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ce5a54/2). This gives the result:

```
|       DATE | MAXDAILYPOWER | TOTALDAILYPOWER |
------------------------------------------------
| 2012-01-01 |           789 |             854 |
| 2012-01-02 |           789 |             280 |
| 2012-02-01 |            89 |              99 |
```

Edit #1, if you want to `GROUP BY` month, then you could use:

```
select month(date) Month, 
  max(value) MaxDailyPower,
  sum(case when col in ('DailyPower1', 'DailyPower2') then value end) TotalDailyPower
from
(
  select date, 'DailyPower' as col, DailyPower as value
  from yourtable
  union all
  select date, 'DailyPower1' as col, DailyPower1 as value
  from yourtable
  union all
  select date, 'DailyPower2' as col, DailyPower2 as value
  from yourtable
) src
group by month(date)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ce5a54/5)

Comment: Hi works OK, so how would I also gorup this by month?  select date, 
  max(value) kWhOpenHrs,
  sum(case when col in ('zkWhClsedAndOccupied', 'zkWhClsedAndNotOccupied') then value end) kWhClsedTotal
from
(
  select date, 'zkWhOpenHrs' as col, kWhOpenHours as value
  from dbo.tblDailyPowerConsumption
  union all
  select date, 'zkWhClsedAndNotOccupied' as col, kWhClosedAndNotOccupied as value
  from dbo.tblDailyPowerConsumption
  union all
  select date, 'zkWhClsedAndOccupied' as col, kWhClosedAndOccupied as value
  from dbo.tblDailyPowerConsumption
) src

GROUP BY Date

Comment: @EugeneBennett See my edit with how you would change your query.  Also what database are you using?  This query could be altered to work with a specific database product.

Comment: Hi sorry not quite, I'd like to find the max value per day, which works fine, I would have a value for each day, I then need to display each day in a chart for a month at a time ie 31 days... Thanks

Comment: @EugeneBennett can you edit your OP with some sample data and then the desired result?

Comment: I sorted it, added WHERE MONTH(date) = '12' before I group by date... Thanks

Comment: @EugeneBennett glad you figured it out. If this answer was helpful to you then be sure to accept it via the checkmark to the left of the answer. It will help future visitors and you will get site rep for accepting.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select date,
       (case when DailyPower > DailyPower1 and DailyPower > DailyPower2 then DailyPower
             when DailyPower1 > DailyPower2 then DailyPower1
             else DailyPower2
       ) as MaxDailyPower,
       coalesce(DailyPower1, 0) + Colaesce(DailyPower2) as DailyPowerSUm
from t
where date between '2012-01-01' and '2012-03-31'  -- for the filter
```

This assumes that there is one row per date i nyour data.